# regarding computing the centroid of high dimensional data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, clustering, anomaly-detection, multivariate-distribution

In scikit-learn, or other python libraries, are there any existing implementations to compute centroid for high dimensional data sets?

Comment: In case the number of instances is very high, a simple solution is to take a random subset.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `np.mean` along the axis that you care about. Let's say you have 100 vectors of 1200 dimensions each, and you want a centroid vector of dimension 1200. Then the following code would work:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.random.rand(100, 1200)
>>> centroid = np.mean(data, axis=0)
>>> centroid.shape
(1200,)
```

Here's documentation for the [function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).